# How to use Facebook Login v2.0 with dotnetopenauth OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 application that was created from the web template in VS2012 so it uses DotNetOpenAuth and the following code for authentication.

```
internal class ExternalLoginResult : ActionResult
    {
        public ExternalLoginResult(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            Provider = provider;
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public string Provider { get; private set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; private set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
        }
    }
```

I want to use Facebook Login v2.0 and I can do this using the Javascript SDK but I can't work out if it's possible to specify the version for oAuth authentication.

I know that it's possible to specify v2.0 in the URL but I can't see where this URL can be configured.

Does anybody know how to do this - or is it hard-coded into DotNetOpenAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the solution I have found is to implement a custom OAuth client as follows (as found in this post [http://forums.asp.net/t/1847724.aspx?+Urgent+How+can+I+get+ExtraData+from+OAuthWebSecurity+):-](http://forums.asp.net/t/1847724.aspx?+Urgent+How+can+I+get+ExtraData+from+OAuthWebSecurity+%29%3a-)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public class FacebookV2Client : DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client
    {
        private const string AuthorizationEP = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth";
        private const string TokenEP = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/oauth/access_token";
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly string _appSecret;

        public FacebookV2Client(string appId, string appSecret)
            : base("facebook")
        {
            this._appId = appId;
            this._appSecret = appSecret;
        }


        protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
        {
            return new Uri(
                        AuthorizationEP
                        + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                        + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                        + "&scope=email,user_about_me"
                        + "&display=page"
                    );
        }

        protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken
            );
            dynamic data = Json.Decode(content);
            return new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {
                    //The behaviour here is unusual. If you request data.username it holds 
                    //the public Facebook username (Timeline address) instead of the email address that DotetOpenAuth returns as username.
                    //This complicates matters as some users will login with their mobile rather than their email address so what do we use as username?
                    "username",
                    data.email
                },
                {
                    "id",
                    data.id
                },
                {
                    "name",
                    data.name
                },
                {
                    "photo",
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/" + data.id + "/picture"
                },
                {
                    "email",
                    data.email
                }
            };
        }

        protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                TokenEP
                + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                + "&client_secret=" + this._appSecret
                + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                + "&code=" + authorizationCode
            );

            NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(content);
            if (nameValueCollection != null)
            {
                string result = nameValueCollection["access_token"];
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in AuthConfig.cs

```
string facebook_appId = "Your appId";
string facebook_appSecret = "Your appSecret";

OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(
    new FacebookV2Client(
        appId: facebook_appId,
        appSecret: facebook_appSecret),
        "facebook", null
);
```

As you can see, the overridden GetUserData method has thrown up something unusual. In the standard Facebook client, response.username contains the users Facebook email address but in this implementation data.username contains the public Facebook username (Timeline address), hence the reason why I'm populating username with data.email. This complicates matters as some users will login with their mobile rather than their email address so I assume that response.username (in the standard Facebook client) will return either the email or mobile number depending on how the user signed-up for Facebook. So how do I decide which field should populate username in this custom implementation? Or is the correct answer to use the public Facebook username (Timeline address (e.g. "joe.blogs.999"). Is there a reason why I shouldn't do that?

Does anybody have an answer please?

Comment: I eventually decided that where the email address isn't provided by Facebook, I will require the user to enter it in the registration process. I feel this is better as it allows me to use unique email as the username for users signing up with local username and password.

Comment: If anybody wants to do this in MVC5 I have a solution for that too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633894/how-to-change-authentication-endpoint-to-use-facebook-loginv2-url-with-owin-secu/28887561#28887561