# How to change authentication endpoint to use Facebook LoginV2 URL with OWIN security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I previously asked a question about doing this in MVC4 and found my own solution.

[How to use Facebook Login v2.0 with dotnetopenauth OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136770/how-to-use-facebook-login-v2-0-with-dotnetopenauth-oauthwebsecurity-requestauthe)

I am upgrading my project to MVC5 so I'm moving to Facebook authentication with OWIN security rather than oAuth. In MVC4 I implemented my own Facebook client so that I could override the default authentication endpoint URL to use the V2 URL. I can't see how I can do this using app.UseFacebookAuthentication because it doesn't take a client parameter.

Facebook require all apps to use the v2 login by April so I'm really surprised that I can't find any existing questions on this. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the changes that Bruno suggested:-

1. Upgrade Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook to 3.0.1
2. In Startup.Auth.cs
   the call to app.UseFacebookAuthentication should be changed to look
   like something like this (note that this is NOT just 3 extra lines
   for the endpoints):-

   ```
       app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
       {
           AppId = facebook_appId,
           AppSecret = facebook_appSecret,
           AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth",
           TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/oauth/access_token",
           UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me"
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. Please check this working item of the katana project:

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/363

Check this also:

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/Tratcher/Katana/contribution/7720#!/tab/changes

I have updated to the latest nuget pakage and this is already available. So, you can now change the authentication endpoints when creating FacebookAuthenticationOptions. This worked for me and is already in production. I had just one problem: the old application cookie was not recognised, meaning that all users will have to authenticate again.